# Default value getting overriden by destructured array in function parameter

Tags: javascript, typescript, destructure

I am trying to understand the basics of typescript and javascript and have following code

```
function b (val = false, arr1, arr2)  {
  console.log('val is:',val); //has 1
  console.log('array val 1:',arr1); //has 2
  console.log('array val 2:',arr2); //has undefined
}
const a = () => {
  const ba = [1,2];
  b(...ba);
}
a();
```

`val` is getting value 1 instead of false. This behavior is same even if I define a typescript datataype like function b `(val:boolean = false, arr1, arr2)`. Should the value of val not be false? What I was thinking would happen was `arr1` and `arr2` will get values `1` and `2` respectively and `val` will get `false` as it has a default value.

Comment: The default value should only be used if there is nothing passed, but you are essentially calling `b(1,2,undefined)`.  Argument order matters; JS has no way to know you want it to skip the first argument.

Comment: TypeScript does not change how your code works at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just omit the first parameter. You should pass undefined for the parameter that you want to default:

```
b(undefined, ...ba)
```

Also, note that there's no destructured array, what you're using is "spread" syntax in your function call.

If you want your parameters to also be an array you can:

```
function b (val = false, ...arr)  {
  console.log('val is:',val); //has false
  console.log('array val 1:',arr[0]); //has 1
  console.log('array val 2:',arr[1]); //has 2
}
b(undefined, ...[1,2]);
```